# JS: An element per click

Tags: javascript

I am working on a game, in the game I have an array of numbers:

```
var moves = [1, 7, 3, 7, 5, 9, 3, 1];
```

Every time a User clicks on a button, I want a single element displayed to the User. For example, the first time I click a button it shoots out "1" the next time I click the button it shoots out "7" etc...

I tried to use a .forEach loop on it but I get ALL elements displayed to me at once. How do I get the elements one at a time?

```
   nextBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
      moves.forEach(function(element) {
      console.log(element)
      })
    }
   )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `i % moves.length` given `i=0` outside the click function so that it get the value of the array in circular manner.

```js
var moves = [1, 7, 3, 7, 5, 9, 3, 1];
var nextBtn = document.getElementById('btn');
var i=0;
nextBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
   var index = i % moves.length;
   console.log(moves[index]);
   i++;
})
```

```html
<button id='btn'>click me</button>
```

Comment: That was super fast response.

Comment: @j_nguyen glad to help. You can tick mark the answer if it was helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

what you can do, you can have a variable which actually stores the count of click. Every time you click on button, it will be increased by 1.

```js
var counter = 0;
nextBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
      console.log(moves[counter++]);
      counter = counter % moves.length;
    }
   )
```

Comment: Will not work if the `counter++` has value greater than the length of `moves` array

Comment: and what happens if counter exceeds length of the array ? :P

Comment: Thanks @AnkitAgarwal. I improved my answer.

Comment: @Anki now this is a same answer as mine so what is the value of posting the answer

Answer (score 0):

Add a `data-move="0"` to the element, something like

```
<div id="btn" data-move="0">next</div>
```

You can then keep track of the moves-number without any additional global variables by updating the data-attribute.

Your script becomes:

```
var moves = [1, 7, 3, 7, 5, 9, 3, 1];
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener("click", function() {
       //get the current index of move
       var index = parseInt(this.getAttribute("data-move"));

       //test if the move is valid
       if(moves[index]==undefined){
          alert("Game over")
          return;
       }

       console.log(moves[index]);
       //set the next move
       this.setAttribute("data-move",index+1);
    })
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wnkocm84/7/)